# Square region similar to CLRegion

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, core-location

Is there a way to store a square location region similar to the way you would store a circular CLRegion?

Currently, when initializing a `CLRegion` I call:

```
– initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:
```

This creates a CLRegion in the shape of a circle. I want to be able to create a region similar to this but in a square shape. I need to store a square map region of variable size that I could hit test similar to the `CLRegion` method `– containsCoordinate:`.

I have looked at `MKCoordinateRegion` as well although I am not sure if it will work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: OK, then *what are you trying to do*? As you obviously can't init CLRegion to other than the default methods.

Comment: I was wondering if there were some other class that would allow me to get this functionality. My question isn't very clear. Fixing that now.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully what I'm trying to get at is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a class to handle this for me: [cknadler/CKSquareRegion](https://github.com/cknadler/CKSquareRegion).

I used coordinate math from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any class in existence. But I don't think it would be that hard to create one yourself.

Assuming the square is aligned parallel to latitudinal  lines, you'd just have to check that the lat and longs are within a certain range.

Comment: This actually ended up being a lot more complicated than I initially thought it would. Your answer pointed me in the right direction though. I ended up making a class: [CKSquareRegion](https://github.com/cknadler/CKSquareRegion).